# Error sending firebase push Notification from Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a flutter application that should receive a notification every time my database is updated.

The database is handled separately using Angular. However, when I make a POST request from angular to firebase to send a notification, I get the following error when I log the Response:

[image]

**Here's the code:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private CustomService: CustomService) {}
  onButtonClick() {
    this.CustomService.pushNotification().subscribe((Response) => {
      console.log(Response);
    });
  }
}
```

**And here's the service code:**

```
export class CustomService{
  // I also do not know if this is the correct format to send
  myNotification: Object = {
    notification: {
      title: 'Angualr Notification',
      body: 'Displayed from Angular: App is in backgroud or closed!',
    },
    data: {
      title: 'Angular Notification',
      body: 'Displayed From Angular: App is open',
      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
    },
    topic: 'all_users',
  };

  FirebaseProjectURL: string "https://console.firebase.google.com/project/dummy-project-123/";

  pushNotification(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post<Object>(this.FirebaseProjectURL, this.myNotification);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of searching here's what I should be doing:

```
export class MyCrudService {
  // Request Body
  myNotification: Object = {
    condition: "('all_users' in topics)",
    notification: {
      title: 'Notification title',
      body: 'Notification message',
    },
    data: {
      title: 'Notification title',
      body: 'Displayed',
      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
    },
  };

  // Request URL and Header
  FirebaseProjectURL: string = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization:'key=AAAA7k...5mHaW', // The full Server key
  });
  options = { headers: this.headers };

  pushNotification(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post<Object>(
      this.FirebaseProjectURL,
      this.myNotification,
      this.options
    );
  }
}
```

I came at "myNotification" by luck in the internet and couldn't find anything in the docs about the POST request body.

If someone has a link on the possible "keys" myNotification should have, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making a correct request, it also seems that your URL is not pointing towards a database but a project instead. Firebase database storage URL's also generally look something like this: `https://databaseName.firebaseio.com`. This means you should setup a database in your firebase project and then use that URL in order to make requests.

I suggest also reading more about how the firebase database works in the documentation:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database.

Comment: I'm familiar with the database, but still learning about how the push notifications are handled (The push request sent from Web to a mobile device specifically). You can check my response.